# LYX: how to mark power set?

Tags: lyx

This is my first time here and I did my best to figure out if such a question is in place here. If I missed something I apologize.

My questions is how can I mark a power set in the lyx document editor?

For example: I'd like to write P(A) when A represents a set, but in the special marking normally used for the power set. I assume there should be a '\shortcut' kind of thing, but I'm new to lyx and can't find one.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have been migrated here. Please register to this site with the same account as on `mathoverflow.net`! Could you please explain a bit, how you would like the `P(A)` to look like? If necessary, draw a picture. I can't help you on LyX, but many people will be able to write some LaTeX `\shortcut` (called macro) for you.

Comment: There are several common ways to denote power set, for example `$\mathcal{P}(A)$`, even plain `$P(A)$` is fine. Just *please* do not abuse for this purpose the Weierstraß elliptic function symbol $\wp$, as many clueless people do.

Comment: Thank you both very much. @EmilJeřábek, `$\mathcal{P}(A)$` was exactly what I was looking for - Would make a valid answer... That's how it looks in my homework pages. @LaRiFaRi, thanks for naming the macro for me, this will help me a lot in future questions. I was afraid this group didn't like ignorant LYX users as myself, Thanks for the nice welcome...

Comment: @EmilJeřábek consider transforming your comment into an answer. It will make it more noticeable for others (and you will get the reputation you deserve).

Answer (score 10):

I find that `$\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{A})$` gives me the result I want:

[image: rendered]

Answer (score 3):

`$\frak{P} (\mathbb{A})$` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want the output of your power set to resemble something like this:

[image]

The above requires [`amssymb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb) to show the special P. For this, "load always" Document > Settings > Math Options > `amssymb`:

[image]

Now, there are a couple of ways to do this:

1. ### Pure LyX

   At the start of your document, Insert > Math > Macro... For the `newcommandname`, type `powerset`. For the TeX component of the math macro, type `\mathbb P`, <kbd>→</kbd>, `(\#1)`. Leave the LyX component of the math macro empty.

   Now when you type a regular (inline) math formula (Insert > Math > Inline Formula), typing `\powerset` changes the input to use your macro:

   [image]
2. ### Pure LaTeX

   In your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble, add

   ```
   \newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathbb{P}(#1)}
   ```

   Within any (inline) math formula, insert an ERT

   [image]

For more information, see [How to enter Math Macros](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/MathMacros).